# In 2011, could a UK visa holder go to France without a French visa?

Tags: visas, uk, france, bangladeshi-citizens

In 2011, could a Bangladeshi citizen, with a Bangladeshi passport and a valid UK visa, enter France without needing an additional French visa?

Answer (score 5):

No. There was no such agreement ever.